# Whats the equivalent of this Python sequence in R?

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I have this data frame with a few columns but the ones I'll be focusing here are `accident_severity` and `day_of_week`.  Both them are categorical data and I'm trying to count the number of accidents in a given day of the week.

The way I'd do this in Python would be something like:

```
df.value_counts().groupby(['accident_severity']).sum()
```

How can I accomplish this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent in `tidyverse` would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    count(day_of_week, accident_severity) %>%
    group_by(accident_severity) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(n), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
rowSums(table(df[c("day_of_week", "accident_severity")]))
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but would you mind to explain me where did that 'n' in 'n = sum(n)' came from?

Comment: @Marcos The `count` by default creates a summarised column with name `n`.  If you want to change the name, specify `name = "n1"` etc in the `count`